# selenium automation signing to google cloud throws networks error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform, selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing

I'm using selenium & selenium wire in my project. I'm writing flows to log in google cloud portals..

I enter my google cloud mail then, press on continue in Google sign in and then it log in to gcp.

I got some errors:

> Request has invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other...

> net:: ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED

[image]

[image]

when I do the same flow **manually** without automation, with the same credentials, it works fine and no any network error.

my web driver

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from seleniumwire.webdriver import ChromeOptions

def test_gcp_flow():

    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs')
    options.add_argument('--log-level=2')
    options.add_argument('--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process')
    options.add_argument("--ignore_ssl")
    options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--dns-prefetch-disable")
    options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('disable-web-security')
    options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get('....any-hidden-url')
    # more flow actions - then it open gcp portal
```

I added openssl.cnf (without this openssl, it shows me TLS ssl issue) to run it locally in my test using Pycharm:

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation
```

I tried to add some change the chrome options that added to selenium driver but nothing has changed, still same error.

**I tried to use Firefox webdriver and it works good without any network issue.**
Maybe it's any chrome cache issue? because some days ago it worked me with chrome..

what I'm expecting is that to sign in to gmail without network/token issues.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible options:

1. Google detects Selenium and prevents login with it for security reasons. Well selenium web driver injects recognizable javascript to the browser, and you can detect it using a simple script.
2. You have an authentication cookie in your browser that is not used with Selenium.
   Each Selenium session initiates itself completely clean. You can save your cookies with `pickle` for instance and then inject it to Selenium web driver with Python. Although I would avoid it if you cant store it encrypted in a secure place and fetch it during run time (or else - at some point it will be stolen no matter how much you think you are secured).

By the way if its something that you really need - YOU are a paying customer, maybe google has an available solutions for this kind of need.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try using selenium wire with an undetected chrome-driver.

`pip install selenium-wire`

`pip install undetected-chromedriver`

```py
from seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = {}
    chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=hash')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    browser = Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options, options=chrome_options)
    browser.get('your url')


    ... your rest of the code
```

I hope it resolves the issue.